# Search for objects within a collection with Contains() and Where()

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do a search within an `ObservablaCollectio`n, and in addition to the `Contains()` method, also `Where()`, however, does not allow me to insert both of them into the same search. how could I solve?

```
resultSearch = MyCollection
.Where(x => x.Nota != null 
   && x.Nota.ToUpper()
    .Contains(TestoSearch.Text.ToUpper()) 
  && x.IconDiaries
    .Where(x=> x.id == iconSearch[0].id))
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Dt).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, `Where` method should have inside of it something which is `bool` value. Inside of your **Where** query you have `x.IconDiaries.Where(x=> x.id == iconSearch[0].id)` which cannot be converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change `x.IconDiaries.Where` to `x.IconDiaries.Any`

```
resultSearch = MyCollection.Where(x => x.Nota != null && x.Nota.ToUpper().Contains(TestoSearch.Text.ToUpper()) && x.IconDiaries.Any(x=> x.id == iconSearch[0].id)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Dt).ToList();
```